# How to make double validation?

Tags: python

I have one doubt regarding coding in Python.

Imagine the following case:

I would like to make 2 validations for a database where I have an interface which has to check, first if user fields are different from 0, and then it should appear a message such as 'Please fill fields' and then if the user input is in the database or not (e.g. if a material X exists in the database, if not should appear another error).

In this case, what is a good approach to do that? Create 2 different def functions? Or perhaps make two 'if'?

I am new to Python and Programming.

Thanks and Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
database = ["","Wood","Steel","Iron",""]

def InFillCheck(database):
    sizeBool = False
    index = 0
    innerCounter = 0
    while sizeBool == False:
        for material in database:
            if material == "":
                try:
                    userInput = input("Please enter new material: ")
                    if userInput in database:
                        raise Exception
                    index = database.index(material)
                    database[index] = userInput
                    print(database)
                except:
                    print("It is already in the database")
        innerCounter = innerCounter + 1
        if innerCounter == len(database):
            sizeBool = True


InFillCheck(database)
```

For further details, you can check the links below,

```
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/exception-handling-python
```

You can also improve my code, I tried to give you an idea and start point.